# Java: Refactor Multiple Stand-Alone Scripts into One Script

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, architecture, intellij-13

I have multiple stand-alone scripts that query a database (each script queries a different source database) and insert the data into another database local to the script. Each script is scheduled via cronjob making things relatively easy and segregated. I need to combine all those scripts into one and I am looking for pointers on a design approach (assuming the one application will now run as a start-up process).

Two high-level approaches I am thinking about are:

```
1) Placing each script into its own package and run a pseudo-cron from main
   if (time = 7pm) then run script package #1
   if (time = 10 after the hour) then run script package #2

2) Place each script in its own Thread and Thread.sleep() it
```

Any suggestions and links to supporting documentation would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What database technology / platform are you using?

Comment: Why are you combining them into one ? What problem are you trying to solve ?

Comment: This will be using Oracle for the fetch and MySQL for the local store. We were given the directive to get our projects down to the minimum number of repositories. Since all these scripts logically do the same thing (fetch a List and Store the List) I figured it could go into the one script.

Comment: What do you define as a "repository"?

Comment: With these scripts being run by cronjobs - are they "Java" or "JavaScript"?  I see you tagged the question 'Java' but I can't see how that's relevant.

Comment: As for a repository, using Intellij when I enable VSC and commit to git then push to its own repo remotely. I am using Java for these not JavaScript, but I called them scripts.

Answer (score 0):

this (what I am about to write) doesn't feel worthy of an "answer" but it's better than using than comments.  Also, I don't have specific knowledge of either MySQL or Oracle, so this will be generic.

Reading your situations, I feel there's so much more going on here than simply 'combining scripts'.

> We were given the directive to get our projects down to the minimum
> number of repositories.

Is it okay to have multiple scripts in the one repo?  I'm assuming here that at the very least you can have one project/folder with any number of script files in it.  I'm not sure why that means you have to have one script file.  And this comment...

> Placing each script into its own package

...seems a bit odd - I'm not sure how you have 'one script' and 'each script in separate packages' :)

> I am looking for pointers on a design approach (assuming the one
> application will now run as a start-up process)

Managing (scheduling, running and monitoring) jobs is complicated to do reliably from scratch, but fortunately its a common challenge so the right tooling exists -
have you checked out the [MySQL event scheduler](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event)?

If you weren't familiar with that, have a look and see if it might work for you.  If it looks promising, see what guidance the docs have which might inform how you compose your scripts.

The reading and learning you do now might seem like too much effort for this specific problem, but it will pay-off in the long-term.

Comment: I was under the impression that each script/application should be in its own repository that's why I was asking about combining them into one application to accomplish that requirement. If I can store multiple applications in the same repository then that would be ideal.

Comment: I am thinking now maybe an IntelliJ project (empty) with multiple modules (each module being the application/script)